# Android keystores: Debug/Release key for each app?

Tags: android, google-play, keytool

I'm getting ready to release an app on the android market and going through the docs for creating debug/release keys. Am I supposed to have a Debug/Release key for each application, or just a general Debug and Release key to use for all applications?

> "...You use debug mode when you are developing and testing your
>   application. You use release mode when you want to build a release
>   version of your application that you can distribute directly to users
>   or publish..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have to create more than one release keystore to sign your app... only one is sufficient even more, if you intent to release an update to your app. , it must be signed withe the same keystore.

Comment: Ok, so one release key and one debug key to use for signing all applications?

Comment: for releasing, you don't need the debug key. you only need one release keystore to sign your app with and if you have any map then you'll need a maps api key as well.

Comment: Great, thanks for the note about the maps key. Yeah, I'll have a map as well.

Comment: Just for clarity, you are signing with a key that is _within_ a keystore.  A keystore can contain multiple keys (such as your debug and release keys in the same keystore).

Answer (score 3):

"In general, the recommended strategy for all developers is to sign all of your applications with the same certificate, throughout the expected lifespan of your applications" - [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies)

The link also lists some of the reasons why it's better to use a single key for all your applications.